# Declaring an empty destructor prevents the compiler from calling memmove() for copying contiguous objects

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization, x86-64

Consider the following definition of `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
    uint64_t data;
};
```

Now, consider the following definition of `Bar`, which has the same data member as `Foo`, but has an **empty** *user-declared* destructor:

```
struct Bar {
    ~Bar(){} // <-- empty user-declared dtor
    uint64_t data; 
};
```

Using gcc 8.2 with `-O2`, the function `copy_foo()`:

```
void copy_foo(const Foo* src, Foo* dst, size_t len) {
    std::copy(src, src + len, dst);
}
```

results in the following assembly code:

```
copy_foo(Foo const*, Foo*, size_t):
        salq    $3, %rdx
        movq    %rsi, %rax
        je      .L1
        movq    %rdi, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        jmp     memmove
.L1:
        ret
```

The assembly code above calls `memmove()` in order to perform the copy of the contiguous `Foo` objects. However, the function below, `copy_bar()`, which does exactly the same as `copy_foo()`, but for `Bar` objects:

```
void copy_bar(const Bar* src, Bar* dst, size_t len) {
    std::copy(src, src + len, dst);
}
```

generates the following assembly code:

```
copy_bar(Bar const*, Bar*, size_t):
        salq    $3, %rdx
        movq    %rdx, %rcx
        sarq    $3, %rcx
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        jle     .L4
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L6:
        movq    (%rdi,%rax,8), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, (%rsi,%rax,8)
        addq    $1, %rax
        movq    %rcx, %rdx
        subq    %rax, %rdx
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        jg      .L6
.L4:
        ret
```

This assembly code doesn't call `memmove()`, but performs the copy by itself.

Of course, if `Bar` is instead defined as:

```
struct Bar {
    ~Bar() = default; // defaulted dtor
    uint64_t data;
};
```

Then, both functions result in identical assembly code, since `Foo` also has a defaulted destructor.

Is there any reason why user-declaring an empty destructor in a class prevents the compiler from generating a call to `memmove()` to copy contiguous objects of that class?

Comment: Well, pedantically, there's obviously a reason, buried inside the compiler's guts, why it fails to implement this particular optimization. But no, there's nothing in the standard that prevents it. The destructor has no observable effect.

Comment: wait, is calling `memmove` the optimization, or is _not_ calling it?

Comment: @TimRandall: Calling `memmove` is the optimization: this is a copy loop for `size_t len` qwords, so a not-unrolled loop that copies 1 qword at a time is very sub-optimal.  Especially with all that loop overhead: it's 6 uops on Haswell for example, so it can only copy 1 qword per 1.5 clocks.  That's terrible; it's easy to write a loop that copies 16 bytes per clock (with SSE, which is baseline for x86-64), for data that's hot in L1d cache, without even unrolling.  (load / store / add / cmp+jcc = 4 uops).

Comment: So there's a big missed-optimization in the copy loop, but calling memmove is good for potentially-large unknown size copies.  The libc implementation can use AVX 256-bit loads/stores to copy 32 bytes at a time on CPUs that support AVX, even if the main program is only compiled for generic x86-64.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) can only be used on objects which are [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), which requires a [trivial destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor). Trivial destructors require that the destructor is not user-provided.

In your code for `Bar`:

> ```
> struct Bar {
>     ~Bar(){} // <-- empty user-declared dtor
>     uint64_t data; 
> };
> ```

The destructor is user-provided, so `Bar` is not *TriviallyCopyable*. Thus it would be incorrect in general for the compiler to generate a call to `std::memmove`.

---

By the as-if rule, the compiler could theoretically detect that the destructor is empty and thus equivalent to being trivial, but it's apparent that this optimization is not included in the implementation of `std::copy`.

The [implementation of `std::copy` from libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/866cd688d1b72b0700a7e001428bdf2fe73fbf64/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#L394) uses the equivalent of [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) which is defined to report `Bar` as not trivially copyable. Enabling this optimization would require libstdc++ to have a special type trait to detect this special case which is trivially avoidable by writing `~Bar() = default;`

Comment: It would not be incorrect, since destructor doesn't have side effects. It is just a missing optimization.

Comment: @SergeyA: well it would be incorrect in the C++ abstract machine, but not in any normal / sane asm compile output.  But it's C++ library code that's looking fo / doing this optimization.  I guess you could argue that libstdc++ could know that its own `std::memmove` implementation (in terms of a GNU C `__builtin` function maybe?) was safe in this case, but really this answer is making the excellent point that the compiler needs to find it after compilation because the library code can't do it.

Comment: "trivially avoidable" - I love that :)

Answer (score 7):

When you declare your own destructor that class is no longer trivially destructable nor trivially copyable.  `std::memmove` requires that the object passed to is trivially copyable so it can't be used on the class anymore.

The standard doesn't pose a requirement on the implementation to check and see if your destructor is actually non trivial, it just defaults to all user defined destructors being non trivial.

If your destructor is truly trivial then there is no reason to write one.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [`std::memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) says :

> If the objects are not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memmove is not specified and may be undefined.

[TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) requires that :

> - Every copy constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every move constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every copy assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - Every move assignment operator is trivial or deleted
>     at least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted
> - **Trivial non-deleted destructor**

A [trivial destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor) requires that :

> - **The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or explicitly defined as defaulted on its first declaration)**
> - The destructor is not virtual (that is, the base class destructor is not virtual)
> - All direct base classes have trivial destructors
> - All non-static data members of class type (or array of class type) have trivial destructors

By adding a user-provided destructor, your type is no longer trivially copyable and passing it to `std::memmove` is unspecified or undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real explanation for that. Declaring a custom destructor (even when empty) makes class not Trivially Destructible. (not POD in old parlance).

Compiler seems to be not able to gather the fact that destructor is not doing anything and can be omitted. You can call it a missing optimization, if you want.